# library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'X64'

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2017

I'm using CUDA 9.2 to simulate ray tracing with OpenGL.

I just found out that since my version of CUDA does not support x86 build, so I should use x64 library.

But there's still probrem.

All glut functions that require opengl32.lib make **"unresolved external symbol error"**.

I thought the linker link the opengl32.lib file from x86 folder, but

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64\OPENGL32.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'X64'**

as you can see, my opengl32.lib was definitely in x64 folder.

How can I fix this problem?
How can I use openGL with CUDA?

Comment: I fail to see how that issue is related to CUDA. Create a new project, link with opengl32.lib and when that works link CUDA.

Comment: It's always called opengl**32**.dll regardless if 32 bit or 64 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may have a targeting machine platform setting in your CUDA project.

Try see in your project settings -> CUDA -> Common targeting machine platform and change it to 32-bit.

[image]

But after CUDA 9.0 version the 86 platform is not supported much
[details](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1027220/cuda-setup-and-installation/vs2017-cuda9-can-not-compile-32bit-cuda-project-but-can-successfully-compile-64bit-cuda-project-/).

The solution are using old CUDA or new libraries your project depends on.

Answer (score 0):

## Change the active solution Platforms from x64 to x86

I was using visual studio 2022.

You can do it from the settings: Build > Configuration manager > Active Solution Platform > change from x64 to x86

or you can simply do it right from outside from here: [just open the list and change from x64 to x86.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WXxI.png)